# FreeBSD configure package options when installing with pkg

Tags: freebsd

I moved from ports to pkg and I'm trying to find out how can I install package with specific options, like I was able to do with ports (`make config`).

E.g. I need to add LDAP support to sendmail, which is off by default:

```
$ pkg rquery '%Ok %Ov %Od %OD' sendmail+tls+sasl2-8.15.1 | grep LDAP
LDAP off off (null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeBSD packages are currently built with the default options.

If you are not happy with the default options, you have the following options:

1. use the ports. use pkg lock to make sure your custom installation is not accidently reinstalled
2. Make a slave port which defines your custom options. There once was mail/sendmail-ldap but it was deleted two years ago (don't know why)
3. Convince the port maintainer that your favorite option should be the default option. (not feasible in this special case)